# Error in tf.keras.Model when disable run_eagerly

Tags: tensorflow

Recently, I develop a custom model in `tf.keras.Model`. My model definition is:

```
class GeneratePatches(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

   def __init__(self, patch):
       super(GeneratePatches, self).__init__()
       self.patch = patch

   def call(self, images):
       images_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=images,
                                                 sizes=[1, self.patch, self.patch, 1],
                                                 strides=[1, self.patch, self.patch, 1],
                                                 rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                                                 padding='VALID')

       patch_dimension = images_patches.shape[-1]
       N = images_patches.shape[1] * images_patches.shape[2]

       patches = tf.reshape(images_patches, [-1, N, patch_dimension])

       return patches


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

   def __init__(self, input_shape, classes, patch, d_model, n_positions, d_mlp, n_layers):
       super(MyModel, self).__init__()
       self.input_size = input_shape
       self.classes = classes
       self.patch = patch
       self.d_model = d_model
       self.n_positions = n_positions
       self.d_mlp = d_mlp

       self.generate_patches = GeneratePatches(patch=self.patch)


   def __mlp_head(self, X_class):

       X = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(X_class)
       X = Dense(units=self.d_mlp)(X)
       X = gelu(X)
       X = Dropout(rate=0.1)(X)
       X_output = Dense(units=self.classes, activation='softmax')(X)

       return X_output

   def call(self, X, training):

       X = self.generate_patches(X)

       X = Dense(units=1024)(X)

       X = self.__mlp_head(X_class=X[:, 0, :])

       return X
```

Finally, I compile the model and run training with the following commands:

```
model = MyModel(input_shape=(224, 224),
                classes=10, patch=32,
                d_model=1024, n_positions=49,
                d_mlp=1024, n_layers=2)

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=3e-4)

model.compile(loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True)

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset,
                epochs=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

To the best of my knowledge, the `run_eagerly` when sets to `True`, TensorFlow does not optimize the model and therefore we can debug the model. Now, when I set the `run_eagerly` in the compilation of the model to `False`, I got this error:

```
enter code here    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "generate_patches" "                 f"(type GeneratePatches).

in user code:

    line 31, in call  *
        N = images_patches.shape[1] * images_patches.shape[2]

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'


Call arguments received by layer "generate_patches" "                 f"(type GeneratePatches):
  • images=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=float32)
```

I googled it but could not find any useful clue to solve it. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

**PS**: By the way, I am using Tensorflow `2.10.0`

Comment: You can try using `tf.shape(image_patches)` instead of `image_patches.shape`. As per the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape): *Within tf.function or within a compat.v1 context, not all dimensions may be known until execution time. Hence when defining custom layers and models for graph mode, prefer the dynamic tf.shape(x) over the static x.shape*.